# How to I add in the "OR" criteria in APEX multiple filters

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to put in the search for multiple filters interactive report in apex. But the search filter ONE and search filter TWO always end up in "AND" condition in APEX. How do I change to "OR" condition in APEX? meaning the result should SHOW Either search word from ONE OR TWO. NOT ONE AND TWO. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Filter option in IR and select 'Filter' Open and Select multiple Condition as given in following screenshot

[image: Multiple filter in IR]

Comment: Great, It works!!! Thank you. How do i specify the apex to search for whole string 'pattern' instead of searching "p","a","t".....?